# JVM Reflection [Scala]: Return specific class type based on pattern matching on run-time

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I think I have a misunderstanding somewhere that I cant figure this out:

*I want the code responsible for reflection to provide me a return type I can pattern-match for the rest of the static-typed application*.

I like to be safe using types ALL the time during compile-time; however this time I must use reflection for legacy purposes; and I'm trying to avoid bringing the rest of the code under reflection as much as possible; iff I can cast or use `asInstanceOf` sort of a thing during run-time. Here is the class hierarchy I'm working with:

```
 lvl1:                            abstract class A 
                                     /       \
 lvl2:    abstract class B extends A         abstract class C extends A     
                                    /          \
 lvl3[reflection required]:     to reflect class paths
```

As you can see from above, I know that the reflective classes instance are either B or C ALL the time and I don't to go to `lvl1` as I need these return types for further pattern matching down the line.

So first the hierarchy:

```
abstract class Website
abstract class Stackoverflow extends Website
abstract class Reddit extends Website
abstract class Academia extends Stackoverflow
```

Then I reflect the "Academia" on run-time:

```
val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val im = m.reflect("Academia")
```

Now here if I use the `getClass` I get use declared methods to `invoke`, etc.:

```
 im.getClass.getDeclaredMethods = ???  //Set/get the methods
```

However:

- If I want to pattern match on the `getClass` I have the type `Class[_ <: ru.InstanceMirror]`.
- I can't use its instance as it is `java.lang.Class`
- I used `WeakType` and `Recognizer`, as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20), however I get `ru.Type` when I use the Recogniser:

  ```
  //Taken from cited url.
  object Recognizer {
    def recognize[T](x: T)(implicit tag: WeakTypeTag[T]): String =
       tag.tpe match {
         case TypeRef(utype, usymbol, args) => List(utype, usymbol, args).mkString("\n")
       }
    }
  }
  ```

So the question here is is there a way I have a method that could have this signature:

```
 def reflectionIWant (path: String): Either[B,C] = ???
 //... or in our example case 
 def reflectionIant (path: String): Either[Stackoverflow, Reddit] = ???
```

Comment: What value do you actually have? You say you want `def reflectIWant(path: String): Either[Stackoverflow, Reddit]`, but what does `path` represent? And what specific value do you want to get back?